# Issue with IDE's when working with header files in C++

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, ide, clion

I set up 3 C++ files (one header, one main file and a final source file) and try to link them correctly to run, however it seems that I keep getting the same output error in different IDE's. Can anyone see from the error message where this is going wrong? Please see the screenshot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAJP0.png)

I made sure the file names, 'include' statements were all correct but I keep getting the same output. I'm questioning if this is because of the MacBook I am using. MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021, M1 Pro).

Comment: you need to add `functions.cpp` to your sources in the cmake file. In future questions be sure to include a [mre] and any error messages as text, not screenshots

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required here please! Also read the [tour] to the end before posting here!

Comment: ***I made sure the file names, 'include' statements were all correct*** It's a linker error not a problem with includes. The error basically said the function add(int,int) was not implemented in any of the compiled files. @AlanBirtles is correct unless perhaps you did not implement that function (with correct signature) in functions.cpp